# C# Nullable Equality Operations, Why does null <= null resolve as false?

Tags: c#, .net, null, comparison-operators

Why is it that in .NET

```
null >= null
```

resolves as false, but

```
null == null
```

resolves as true?

In other words, why isn't `null >= null` equivalent to `null > null || null == null`?

Does anyone have the official answer?

Comment: It's interesting to note `(object)null >= (object)null` is a compile-error (well, no `>=` defined for it, duh). What is *really* happening with the IL? Of course there is `(int?)null >= (int?)null`, etc, which shows the behavior above.

Comment: Please see the "possible duplicate" before voting to close. While it covers some of the same aspect (and should be read/viewed as a companion question), the responses cover *different angles* as does the question -- in particular the other question already assumes `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an exact duplicate... The other quesiton talks about a specific case where the types of the operands are known (nullable).  This goes a step further is looking for an explanation about the null literals where they have no specified type.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This behaviour is defined in the C# specification ([ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)) in section 14.2.7 (I have highlighted the relevant part):

> For the relational operators
>
> ```
> < > <= >=
> ```
>
> a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type
>   is `bool`. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to each operand type. **The lifted
>   operator produces the value `false` if one or both operands are `null`**. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps
>   the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the `bool` result.

In particular, this means that the usual laws of relations don't hold; `x >= y` does not imply `!(x < y)`.

### Gory details

Some people have asked why the compiler decides that this is a lifted operator for `int?` in the first place. Let's have a look. :)

We start with 14.2.4, 'Binary operator overload resolution'. This details the steps to follow.

1. First, the user-defined operators are examined for suitability. This is done by examining the operators defined by the types on each side of `>=`... which raises the question of what the type of `null` is! The `null` literal actually doesn't have any type until given one, it's simply the "null literal". By following the directions under 14.2.5 we discover there are no operators suitable here, since the null literal doesn't define any operators.
2. This step instructs us to examine the set of predefined operators for suitability. (Enums are also excluded by this section, since neither side is an enum type.) The relevant predefined operators are listed in sections 14.9.1 to 14.9.3, and they are all operators upon primitive numeric types, along with the lifted versions of these operators (note that `string`s operators are not included here).
3. Finally, we must perform overload resolution using these operators and the rules in 14.4.2.

Actually performing this resolution would be extremely tedious, but luckily there is a shortcut. Under 14.2.6 there is an informative example given of the results of overload resolution, which states:

> ...consider the predefined implementations of the binary * operator:
>
> ```
> int operator *(int x, int y);
> uint operator *(uint x, uint y);
> long operator *(long x, long y);
> ulong operator *(ulong x, ulong y);
> void operator *(long x, ulong y);
> void operator *(ulong x, long y);
> float operator *(float x, float y);
> double operator *(double x, double y);
> decimal operator *(decimal x, decimal y);
> ```
>
> When overload resolution rules (§14.4.2) are applied to this set of operators, the effect is to select the first of
>   the operators for which implicit conversions exist from the operand types.

Since both sides are `null` we can immediately throw out all unlifted operators. This leaves us with the lifted numeric operators on all primitive numeric types.

Then, using the previous information, we select the first of the operators for which an implicit conversion exists. Since the null literal is implicitly convertible to a nullable type, and a nullable type exists for `int`, we select the first operator from the list, which is `int? >= int?`.

Comment: I can't up-vote this answer without explanation of why `null >= null` "goes to" `(int?)null >= (int?)null` which makes it eligible for the above "lifted form".

Comment: I left that out because it's quite in depth and it doesn't make a difference to the code in question. I'll add it later :)

Comment: I attempted to go a bit more in depth.  What a pain.  :)

Comment: Updated with my attempt. I believe top-down is truer to the compiler than a bottom-up examination.

Comment: Quoting a standard never provides an answer to the question of "Why", it only sparks a rephrasing of the same question: Why are >= and <= treated in the same way as < and > in regards to lifting when they would be better suited being grouped with ==?

Answer (score 29):

A number of answers appeal to the spec. In what turns out to be an unusual turn of events, *the C# 4 spec does not justify the behaviour specifically mentioned of comparison of two null literals*. In fact, a strict reading of the spec says that "null == null" should give an ambiguity error! (This is due to an editing error made during the cleanup of the C# 2 specification in preparation for C# 3; it is not the intention of the spec authors to make this illegal.)

Read the spec carefully if you don't believe me. It says that there are equality operators defined on int, uint, long, ulong, bool, decimal, double, float, string, enums, delegates and objects, plus the lifted-to-nullable versions of all the value type operators.

Now, immediately we have a problem; this set is infinitely large. In practice we do not form the infinite set of all operators on all possible delegate and enum types. The spec needs to be fixed up here to note that the only operators on enum and delegate types which are added to the candidate sets are those of enum or delegate types that are the types of either argument.

Let's therefore leave enum and delegate types out of it, since neither argument has a type.

We now have an overload resolution problem; we must first eliminate all the inapplicable operators, and then determine the best of the applicable operators.

Clearly the operators defined on all the non-nullable value types are inapplicable. That leaves the operators on the nullable value types, and string, and object.

We can now eliminate some for reasons of "betterness". The better operator is the one with the more specific types. int? is more specific than any of the other nullable numeric types, so all of those are eliminated. String is more specific than object, so object is eliminated.

That leaves equality operators for string, int? and bool? as the applicable operators. Which one is the best?  **None of them is better than the other**.  Therefore this should be an ambiguity error.

For this behaviour to be justified by the spec we are going to have to emend the specification to note that "null == null" is defined as having the semantics of *string equality*, and that it is the compile-time constant true.

I actually just discovered this fact yesterday; how odd that you should ask about it.

To answer the questions posed in other answers about why `null >= null` gives a warning about comparisons to int? -- well, apply the same analysis as I just did. The `>=` operators on non-nullable value types are inapplicable, and of the ones that are left, the operator on int? is the best. There is no ambiguity error for `>=` because there is no `>=` operator defined on bool? or string. The compiler is correctly analyzing the operator as being comparison of two nullable ints.

To answer the more general question about why operators on null *values* (as opposed to *literals*) have a particular unusual behaviour, **see my answer to the duplicate question**.  It clearly explains the design criteria that justify this decision. In short: operations on null should have the semantics of operations on "I don't know". Is a quantity you don't know greater than or equal to another quantity you don't know?  The only sensible answer is "I don't know!" But we need to turn that into a bool, and the sensible bool is "false". But when comparing for equality, most people think that null should be equal to null even though comparing two things that you don't know for equality should also result in "I don't know". This design decision is the result of trading off many undesirable outcomes against one another to find the least bad one that makes the feature work; it does make the language somewhat inconsistent, I agree.

Comment: Very nice answer. I'm finally (somewhat) satisfied.

Comment: `"The spec needs to be fixed up here to note that the only operators on enum and delegate types which are added to the candidate sets are those of enum or delegate types that are the types of either argument."` I believe this is already the case in the 4th edition.

Comment: Also, the `null == null` behaviour is specifically defined by the spec (§14.9.6): "If both of the types A and B are the null type, then overload resolution is not performed and the result is
a constant true or false, as specified in §14.9."

Comment: @Porges: Thanks! What edition of the spec is that quote from? I thought Mads and I removed all references to "the null type" in the v3 spec.

Comment: @Eric: This is all from the 4th edition :)

Comment: @Porges: Then the bound 4th edition has some text in it that the word document does not; perhaps they have gotten out of sync.  I'll check it out when I'm back in my office tomorrow.

Comment: @Eric: Interesting! Just FYI this is the version from the ECMA's website. The wording is identical in the ISO/IEC version.

Comment: @Porges: Got it. We are talking past one another. I am looking at the *C# 4* specification from 2010. You are looking at the fourth revision to the *C# 2* specification, from 2006.  Apparently at one point there was language in the C# 2 spec to handle this case. It must have been deleted accidentally sometime between 2006 and 2010; probably when we removed the references to "the null type".

Comment: @Eric: Oh damn. I thought there was something weird going on here. I based my answer off the ECMA standard so I guess it got stuck in my mind.

Comment: FWIW, I cross checked v2 with v4.  In v4, it is worded differently but more or less says the same thing.  `The predefined reference type equality operators require [...] [b]oth operands are a value of a type known to be a reference-type or the literal null` (§7.10.6 p200).

Comment: @Jeff M : Ah, but the predefined reference type equality operator has been removed from the candidate set because it is worse than the string equality. So that clause doesn't apply.  What we need to do is restore the missing clause which was accidentally removed, which simply says that "null == null" causes overload resolution to be skipped entirely and that expression is logically replaced with "true".

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is inferring that in the case of the comparison operators, the `null` is being implicitly typed as `int?`.

```
Console.WriteLine(null == null); // true
Console.WriteLine(null != null); // false
Console.WriteLine(null < null);  // false*
Console.WriteLine(null <= null); // false*
Console.WriteLine(null > null);  // false*
Console.WriteLine(null >= null); // false*
```

Visual Studio offers a warning:

> *Comparing with null of type 'int?' always produces 'false'

This can be verified with the following code:

```
static void PrintTypes(LambdaExpression expr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(expr);
    ConstantExpression cexpr = expr.Body as ConstantExpression;
    if (cexpr != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", cexpr.Type);
        return;
    }
    BinaryExpression bexpr = expr.Body as BinaryExpression;
    if (bexpr != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", bexpr.Left.Type);
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", bexpr.Right.Type);
        return;
    }
    return;
}
PrintTypes((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => null == null)); // constant folded directly to bool
PrintTypes((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => null != null)); // constant folded directly to bool
PrintTypes((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => null < null));
PrintTypes((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => null <= null));
PrintTypes((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => null > null));
PrintTypes((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => null >= null));
```

Outputs:

```
() => True
        System.Boolean
() => False
        System.Boolean
() => (null < null)
        System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
        System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
() => (null <= null)
        System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
        System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
() => (null > null)
        System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
        System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
() => (null >= null)
        System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
        System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
```

---

Why?

This seems logical to me.  First of all, here's relevant sections of the [C# 4.0 Spec](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E).

The null literal §2.4.4.6:

> The  null-literal can be implicitly converted to a reference type or nullable type.

Binary numeric promotions §7.3.6.2:

> Binary numeric promotion occurs for the operands of the predefined +, –, *, /, %, &, |, ^, ==, !=, >, <, >=, and <= binary operators. Binary numeric promotion implicitly converts both operands to a common type which, in case of the non-relational operators, also becomes the result type of the operation. Binary numeric promotion consists of applying the following rules, in the order they appear here:
>
> • If either operand is of type decimal, the other operand is converted to type decimal, or a binding-time error occurs if the other operand is of type float or double.
>   •   Otherwise, if either operand is of type double, the other operand is converted to type double.
>   •   Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other operand is converted to type float.
>   •   Otherwise, if either operand is of type ulong, the other operand is converted to type ulong, or a binding-time error occurs if the other operand is of type sbyte, short, int, or long.
>   •   Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other operand is converted to type long.
>   •   Otherwise, if either operand is of type uint and the other operand is of type sbyte, short, or int, both operands are converted to type long.
>   •   Otherwise, if either operand is of type uint, the other operand is converted to type uint.
>   •   Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Lifted operators §7.3.7:

> Lifted operators permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types. Lifted operators are constructed from predefined and user-defined operators that meet certain requirements, as described in the following:
>
> • For the relational operators
>   <  >  <=  >=
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator produces the value false if one or both operands are null. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.

The null-literal alone doesn't really have a type.  It is inferred by what it is assigned to.  No assignment takes place here however.  Only considering built-in types with language support (ones with keywords), `object` or any nullable would be a good candidate.  However `object` isn't comparable so it gets ruled out.  That leaves nullable types good candidates.  But which type?  Since neither left nor right operands has a specified type, they are converted to a (nullable) `int` by default.  Since both nullable values are null, it returns false.

Comment: Took a while to get this written out, would be a waste to just not share it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the compiler treats null as if they're integer types.
VS2008 remarks: `"Comparing with null of type 'int?' always produces 'false'"`

Comment: +1 Because I think this answer hints as to WHAT is going on: `null >= null` => `(int?)null >= (int?)null`, but *why*?

Answer (score 2):

When I run

```
null >= null
```

I get a warning saying:

> Comparing with null of type 'int?'
>   always produces 'false'

I wonder why it is casted to an int though.

Comment: +1 Because I think this answer hints as to WHAT is going on: `null >= null` => `(int?)null >= (int?)null`, but *why*?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the compiler is smart enough to figure out that `>= null` will *always* be false and replaces your expression with a constant value of `false`.

Check out this example:

```
using System;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int? i = null;

        Console.WriteLine(i >= null);
        Console.WriteLine(i == null);
    }
}
```

This compiles down to the following code:

```
class Example
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        int? i = new int?();
        Console.WriteLine(false);
        Console.WriteLine(!i.HasValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: But why is `null >= null` always false? This means  `null >= null` is not equivalent to `null == null || null > null`.

Comment: Why is he being downvoted? (Hope I don't get downvoted because I am asking :))

Comment: @Martinho As the answer states, `>= null` is always false.  Therefore `null >= null` is false.  You're correct ("null >= null is not equivalent to null == null || null > null"); if this was true then you wouldn't have witness this behaviour!

Comment: @Kirk: I was more curious as to what led to making the decision that lifted relational operators always yield false if one operand is null. Why "break" the "usual" relations of those operators? Also, it does not matter if the compiler is "smart enough" to figure out that >= null will always be false and optimize it away. Whether it figures that out or not, it will have this behavior, because that's what is written in the spec.

Comment: @Martinho Are you asking why it is in the spec, then?  It is a short circuit evaluation.  There are many short circuits like this, implemented deliberately to minimise the number of calculations.

Comment: @Kirk: The spec says nothing about a short circuit evaluation, because it *isn't* short circuited: `Func<int?> f = () => { Console.Write("foo"); return 42; }; Console.Write(null >= f());` produces "fooFalse". My curiosity is about why ">= null is always false", instead of "> is always false, and >= acts as > || ==, like elsewhere"

Comment: @Martino But `null >=` is not the same as `>= null`.  I am not sure what I'm missing - this answer says that `>= null` is short circuited to always return false.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @Kirk: `>= null` and `null >=` will always return false, but they're *not* short-circuited.

Comment: @Kirk: (Note that the answer says nothing about short circuiting.) Yes, I do disagree. Changing `null >=` to `>= null` in my example yields the same non-short-circuited behavior. It does yield false, but it does not short circuit. Maybe you're misundertanding what [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) means?

Comment: @Martinho @LukeH Surely `a >= b` evaluates to `a != null && b != null && ( a == b || a > b )`, and is short circuiting when b is null?  If I'm misunderstanding short-circuiting then, well I'm just confused.

Comment: @Kirk: You're almost there. `a >= b` compiles to something more like `(a.HasValue & b.HasValue) && a.Value >= b.Value` (notice the first use of & instead of &&), except that `a` and `b` are evaluated only once. Yes, the .Value calls won't be made if one of them is null, but they both are already evaluated, and thus there's effectively no short-circuiting (in which case the evaluation of one of them would be skipped). If the compiler knows one of them to be null, it will optimize a little, but never skip the evaluations.

Comment: @Martinho But the `a.Value >= b.Value` is not evaluated because it comes after `&&` and the `HasValue` was not satisfied.  If the `>=` section is not evaluated, isn't that short circuiting?

Comment: @Kirk: yes, that part is short-circuiting the && operator. But you can't say that >= is short circuiting because of that: both operands are already evaluated by then. `Func<int?> f = () => { throw new Exception(); }; a >= f()` throws, but `Func<bool> f = () => { throw new Exception(); }; false && f()` doesn't. && might evaluate only one operand, but >= *always* evaluates both. That's what makes one short-circuiting, but the other not.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the "official" answer, it's my best guess. But if you're dealing with nullable ints and comparing them, you most likely always want the comparison to return false if you're dealing with two "int?"s that are null. That way if it returns true, you can be sure you've actually compared two integers, not two null values. It just removes the need for a separate null check.

That said, it is potentially confusing if it's not the behaviour you expect!

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is documented in this page about [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx#sectionToggle4). It doesn't give a real explanation for why, but my interpretation is the following. `>` and `<` have no meaning when with regards to `null`. `null` is the absence of a value and thus is only equal to another variable that also has no value. Since there is no meaning for `>` and `<`, that is carried over to `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: But you can define it such that `(X)null >= (X)null` is true, where X defines `>=` (and `<=`). Thus this is a *specific case* of `null >= null` (and differs from the non-legal `(object)null >= (object)null`).

Answer (score 2):

They seem to be mixing paradigms from C and SQL.

In the context of nullable variables, null == null should really yield false since equality makes no sense if neither value is known, however doing that for C# as a whole would cause issues when comparing references.

Comment: Unless... you could compare references some other way like with Object.ReferenceEquals().

Comment: Indeed, but that would break a lot of code.

Comment: +1, I'm pretty sure that this would be the rationale behind *not* defining all lifted equality and inequality operators as returning `false` if either of the operands is null. Remember that `Nullable<T>` wasn't introduced until C#2, by which time developers were used to the `if (myObj == null)` idiom for reference types. It would be weird for the same idiom to work for null references but not for null nullables (and breaking the existing behaviour for ref types would be out of the question).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be "because that's the way those operators are defined in the specification".

From section 8.19 of the [ECMA C# spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm):

> Lifted forms of the `==` and `!=`
>   operators consider two null values
>   equal, and a null value unequal to a
>   non-null value. Lifted forms of the
>   `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` operators
>   return false if one or both operands
>   are null.

Comment: But what makes `null >= null` "lifted"?

Comment: @pst: a lifted operator is typically defined as the extension of the unlifted operator to the nullable domain such that the result is null if either argument is null. Unfortunately, the C# spec uses the term "lifted" even for operators which do not lift the returned value to nullable bool, such as the comparison operators.

Answer (score 1):

This question was a Deja vu, oh wait here it is...

[Why does >= return false when == returns true for null values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399932/why-does-return-false-when-returns-true-for-null-values)

The thing I remember from the other answer was :

> Because Equality is defined separately
>   from Comparability. You can test x ==
>   null but x > null is meaningless. In
>   C# it will always be false.