# Nullable types comparison

Tags: c#

I was doing some comparison between nullable types when I noticed this:

```
int? a = null;
int? b = null;
// a == b; ==> true
// a <= b; ==> false
```

For me, `<=` operator is equivalent to `== OR <` and since `a == b` is `true`, I'm excepting also `true` for `a <= b`.

Doesn't seem illogic for you too?

Why `<=` and `>=` operators were done this way? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: It seems every comparison between two nullable types (except for != and ==) return false. Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: Please stop closing this question as a duplicate, unless the linked question actually answers **why** C# was designed this way. Reopening.

Comment: Surely the "why" is "because the spec says so"?

Comment: This post has some more information on why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730648/c-sharp-nullable-equality-operations-why-does-null-null-resolve-as-false

Comment: @DavidG: Why does the spec say so? Specs are not "words of god", there is usually some rational reason behind it.

Comment: If you want to know why some person choose to do what they did then *ask them*.  We can't possibly tell you why someone else choose to do something that they did.

Comment: @Heinzi: a question should be closed as duplicate if there is a duplicate question that asks the same, not if there is one that actually answers it. Also, the _why_ is either subjective or can be answered only by the language designers

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I agree. However, the first two dupe targets did not satisfy this criterion either.

Comment: @Servy: Oh, yes, when C# is concerned, we usually can. Some of the C# designers are frequent users of StackOverflow. Eric Lippert, for example, has often written great answers to these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Heinzi Then the subjective "why" could quite easily be added to the duplicates. The why and how are so intrinsically linked, that's why I hammered it.

Comment: @Heinzi Funnily enough the dupe is a dupe and the answer given in the latter is by Eric.

Comment: @Heinzi: btw, the _why_ was answered by E.Lippert in the last paragraph of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4731337/284240

Comment: @Heinzi: And in fact I *did* write an answer to this question, in 2010 and again in 2011. Though looking back on them now, I think I did not adequately describe the design problems of the `<=` operator; I mostly concentrated on the problems of the `==` operator.

Comment: @EricLippert: I knew we could count on you. :-)

Comment: More generally: "why" questions are bad questions for SO. An adequate answer to "why is the language this way" would be to re-hash the hours and hours of debate we had about it.  All language oddities like this are attempts to resolve many competing principles that contradict each other.  I am not particularly happy with the decision to make `<=` not have the same semantics as `< || ==`. Nor am I at all happy that `a < b` and `a >= b` are not opposites for nullable values. The compromise position that the C# 2 team arrived at leaves all sides equally disappointed. Good compromise!

Comment: What you should do is re-formulate in your head that on nullable values, `==` is actually *structural equality*, and that `x <= y` means "is x known to be smaller than or equal to y?"  If x is null, then x is unknown, and so x is *not known to be smaller than y*. Once you realize that for nullables, equality and inequality are logically answering different questions, the contradictions disappear.

Comment: More thoughts on the fascinating subject of extending operators to nullables can be found here https://ericlippert.com/2015/08/31/nullable-comparisons-are-weird/ and here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/03/26/null-is-not-false/ and here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/04/12/null-is-not-false-part-two/ and here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/04/19/null-is-not-false-part-three/, and how we generate the code is described starting here https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

Comment: There is great blog about this.[C#/.NET Little Wonders: The Nullable static class](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/30/c.net-little-wonders-the-nullable-static-class.aspx)