# Parametrized Constructor in Struct

Tags: c#

Default constructor is defined for "Class" and for "Struct". But If I declare a class "Point" which has only 1 constructor, and that too a parametrized one, the compiler would not allow me to write

```
Point p = new Point()
```

However, If I have a struct "Point", which again has only 1 parametrized constructor, the compiler will allow me to write

```
Point p = new Point()
```

The question I am asking is why the compiler allowed struct to create an object and stopped the class to create an object?

Note: I am writing this code on C# 6

Comment: And what is your question? You've failed to ask one.

Comment: Correct, this is a behavior of structs. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/575901/51)

Comment: And yet another question with answer from Jon Skeet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Even with your edit, you're still not *asking a question*. All you're doing at the moment is *making an observation*. You have correctly observed that there is a difference between `class` and `struct`, in that `struct`s always have a parameterless constructor (and until C#7, you're not allowed to write it yourself) - but that's covered by any basic introduction to the concept of `struct`s you may care to read.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. The question I am asking is why the compiler allowed struct to create an object and stopped the class to create an object?

Comment: Actually, [Eric Lippert wrote a great comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121625/nullable-types-comparison#comment73323385_43121625) regarding "why" questions, i.e. _"An adequate answer to "why is the language this way" would be to re-hash the hours and hours of debate we had about it."_.

Comment: can you send your C# Code to understand your Question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use classes, you can define whether its object can or cannot be initialized in any particular way.
However, when it comes to struct, it should always be able to be initialized without parameters.

It is best illustrated by the fact that classes can be initialized with `null` when you can't initialize them in specified way, while there is no such option for structs. But structs can be initialized with `default` keyword, which basically calls the parameterless constructor.

**Edited:**
While I was outlining the common rule for `struct` as valuetype, there are actually several ways to initialize `struct` with `null` (or *simulate* it). Th most common is, of course, `Nullable<>`, and it is sufficient for most, if not all, purposes. For those who are curious about how it works and what are the other ways to set `null` to the `struct`, I recommend **C# in Depth**: *Chapter 4. Saying nothing with nullable types* by *Jon Skeet*. Additional information could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503811/how-are-nullable-types-implemented-under-the-hood-in-net).

Comment: I thought the bounty reason was _"Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources"_. I am surprised that the awarded asnwer is an _"In my opinion..."_ type of answer.

Comment: @Dmitriy Volkov Which category belongs nullable struct? It is a struct and can be set to null:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Rekshino Well, yes, there are several ways to set null to a struct, as Jon Skeet discusses in his book. Generally speaking, it very rarely comes to implementing such mechanisms, but if you want to learn about it, you can read about it in "C# in Depth: Chapter 4. Saying nothing with nullable types" by Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Rekshino Here, found something that might interest you if you are curious about such mechanisms. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503811/how-are-nullable-types-implemented-under-the-hood-in-net

Comment: I am not curious about it and I do not need to implement it, it's a standard since c# 2.0. I mean, that in your answer you say, that struct can not to be set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Because a `struct` is a value type, its default value is not null, like a reference type, but an instance with all of its members set to their default values.

So even if you were only allowed to call the parameterized constructor, you could still create a default instance, which would be exactly the same as creating the struct with a default constructor.

For example, given this struct:

```
public struct Point
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Even if you couldn't do this:

```
var p = new Point();
```

You could still do this:

```
var p = default(Point);
```

If `Point` were a class this wouldn't get you an instance, it would get you `null`. But with a struct it gets you an instance.

So there's no reason to prevent use of the default constructor and *pretend* that you can't create a default instance.

Answer (score -1):

Answer to your question(why there is no compile error) you can find on MSDN:

> In C#, **classes and structs are semantically different**.

( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs )

> A struct cannot declare a default constructor (a constructor without
>   parameters) or a destructor.

( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs )

> **Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type**. For information about default values
>   of value types, see Default Values Table.

( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types )