# Inconsistent results when comparing nullable type

Tags: c#

Here is a C#  code fragment that compares to nullables that contains the null value.

```
int? v1 = null;
int? v2 = null;
Console.WriteLine(v1 > v2); /* False (as expected) */
Console.WriteLine(v1 == v2); /* True (as expected) */
Console.WriteLine(v1 > v2 || v1 == v2); /* True (as expected) */
Console.WriteLine(v1 >= v2); /* False Why? */
```

The question relates to the last row, why is the (>=) operator does not behave like (> || ==) combination.

Comment: As per the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051545/993547): "To summarise: any inequality comparison with null (>=, <, <=, >) returns false even if both operands are null."

Comment: That answer really seems to just repeat OP's question though.  All it says is basically "null >= null will always be false" without explaining *why*, which I think is what OP really wants to understand.  Unfortunately, I think "because the spec says so" is going to be the ultimate answer.

Comment: Thanks. Saw this answer but missed the last one.

Comment: null values for comparison return false.  Null is not a numeric value which >= is operating on. There is a pretty big debate on this subject.

Comment: Also read Eric Lipperts blog on this: https://ericlippert.com/2015/08/31/nullable-comparisons-are-weird/

Comment: And more here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4730648/993547

Comment: A little investigation shows that using Nullable.Compare works as expected in all scenarios.

Console.WriteLine(Nullable.Compare(v1, v2) == 0);  // True as expected 
Console.WriteLine(Nullable.Compare(v1, 1) < 0);  // True as expected
Console.WriteLine(Nullable.Compare(1, v2) > 0);  // True as expected