# Wrong compiler warning when comparing struct to null

Tags: c#, comparison, nullable, compiler-warnings, lifted-operators

Consider the following code:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Today;

bool isGreater = t > null;
```

With Visual Studio 2010 (C# 4, .NET 4.0), I get the following warning:

> warning CS0458: The result of the expression is always 'null' of type 'bool?'

This is incorrect; the result is always **`false`** (of type `bool`):

Now, the struct DateTime overloads the `>` (greater than) operator. Any non-nullable struct (like DateTime) is implicitly convertible to the corresponding `Nullable<>` type. The above expression is exactly equivalent to

```
bool isGreater = (DateTime?)t > (DateTime?)null;
```

which also generates the same wrong warning. Here the `>` operator is the **lifted** operator. This works by returning false if `HasValue` of any of its two operands is `false`. Otherwise, the lifted operator would proceed to unwrap the two operands to the underlying struct, and then call the overload of `>` defined by that struct (but this is not necessary in this case where one operand does not `HasValue`).

**Can you reproduce this bug, and is this bug well-known? Have I misunderstood something?**

This is the same for all struct types (not simple types like `int`, and not enum types) which overload the operator in question.

(Now if we use `==` instead of `>`, everything ought to be entirely similar (because DateTime also overloads the `==` operator). But it's not similar. If I say

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Today;

bool isEqual = t == null;
```

I get **no** warning ☹ Sometimes you see people accidentally check a variable or parameter for null, not realizing that the type of their variable is a struct (which overloads `==` and which is not a simple type like `int`). It would be better if they got a warning.)

---

***Update:*** With the C# 6.0 compiler (based on [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform)) of Visual Studio 2015, the incorrect message with `isGreater` above is changed into a CS0464 with a correct and helpful warning message. Also, the lack of warning with `isEqual` above is fixed in VS2015's compiler, but only if you compile with `/features:strict`.

Comment: `[anything] > null` doesn't make any sense to begin with (to me, at least). Interesting question nonetheless, I think it should warn about the `bool` always ending up as `false`.

Comment: May be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/12/11/501544.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/12/14/503533.aspx

Comment: Interestingly, `DateTime.CompareTo(object)` _specifically_ returns `1` when you compare to `null`, whatever the type of object passed in.

Comment: The same warning appears in VS 2012 with .net 4.5 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct: **this is a bug in Visual Studio**. The C# 4.0 standard (§ 7.3.7 Lifted operators) has this to say:

> For the relational operators
>
> ```
> <  >  <=  >=
> ```
>
> […] **The lifted operator produces the value `false` if one or both operands are null.** …

And in fact, in MonoDevelop, you get the following warning instead:

> The result of comparing type `System.DateTime` with `null` is always `false`.

Comment: But, in this `>` case, the result is false, not null. The type of the result is `bool`, not `bool?`.

Comment: @Rawling Is it? That sounds wrong, it should definitely be `bool?` since the operator is lifted.

Comment: Visual Studio seems to think so, but `DateTime.Today > null` gives me `false` of type `bool`, and the asker gets the same, apparently. I agree it's weird.

Comment: @Rawling Duh, of course – otherwise the code wouldn’t even compile. Hehe, funny – so apparently `DateTime` overloads the operator for `null` …

Comment: You: _this is generally true for all operators, not just addition._ No. Please read the section "Lifted operators" of the C# Language Specification. The lifted operators `==` and `>` return `bool` just like the original operator. That's different from the `+` operator. The lifted `+` operator (unary and binary) returns `DateTime?` (nullable) because the unlifted form returns `DateTime` (non-nullable).

Comment: @Jeppe Damn, I remembered that completely wrong. Well, I’ve removed the wrong part of the answer. The note about the VS bug still stands. In that you are definitely correct, and MonoDevelop’s behaviour nicely demonstrates it (even though it doesn’t constitute incontrovertible truth, obviously).

Comment: I found out that Eric Lippert in [an answer elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4400231/1336654) explains the decision process they had when they introduced nullable types. It **was** considered to make things the way you thought they were (so that `>` would return `null`, not `false`), but eventually they decided to do it differently. It looks like they forgot to get rid of some old warnings from before this decision.

Comment: Since this answer is the better one, I'll mark it accepted. After your edits it's a good answer. Nobody gave reference if this was a known bug, so I submitted it. See [this feeback item at Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768940/).

Answer (score 9):

I discovered this error independently while implementing lifted operator behaviour in Roslyn, and I fixed it in Roslyn before I left.

Sorry that I didn't see this when you posted it back in October. Thanks for submitting it to Connect! And many apologies for the error; it is a long-standing error in operator semantic analysis.

Incidentally, I'll be discussing how Roslyn optimizes lifted expressions on http://ericlippert.com later this month (December 2012), so if this subject interests you, check it out:

http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

Comment: There's no need to apologize for not seeing every thread on Stack Overflow. I hope I remember to check your upcoming post on lifted operators.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Today;

bool isGreater = (DateTime?)t > (DateTime?)null;
```

In this scenario what the warning is about is the `t > null`.  That is never going to be true. Because It can't be evaluated.

In this scenario:

```
bool isGreater = (DateTime?)t > (DateTime?)null;
```

We are evaluating  `(DateTime?)t > (DateTime?)null`;

Or essentially in the best case scenario `t > null`;  same as before.  DateTime.Now can never be greater than Undefined, hence the warning.

Comment: I agree it's relevant with a warning, but have you read the warning **message**? It's the text of the warning that is disturbingly wrong, not the fact that a warning is emitted. (Maybe at some time during the development of nullable types they planned to have the lifted operators of comparisons (`>`, `==`, and so on) behave differently, but then changed their minds?)