# How can I return a bool value from a plethora of nullable bools?

Tags: c#, boolean, nullable

With this code:

```
private bool AtLeastOnePlatypusChecked()
{
    return ((ckbx1.IsChecked) ||
            (ckbx2.IsChecked) ||
            (ckbx3.IsChecked) ||
            (ckbx4.IsChecked));
}
```

...I'm stopped dead in my tracks with

```
Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'bool?
```

So how do I accomplish this?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plethora

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can chain together `|`s, using the null-coalescing operator at the end:

```
return (ckbx1.IsChecked | cxbx2.IsChecked | cxbx3.IsChecked | cxbx4.IsChecked) ?? false;
```

The lifted `|` operator returns `true` if either operand is `true`, `false` if both operands are `false`, and `null` if either operand is `null` and the other isn't `true`.

It's not short-circuiting, but I don't think that'll be a problem for you in this case.

Alternatively - and more extensibly - put the checkboxes into a collection of some kind. Then you can just use:

```
return checkboxes.Any(cb => cb.IsChecked ?? false);
```

Comment: Finally I know what "lifted" means. I encountered this term when working with expression trees.

Comment: I was curious about that term too, but it looks like [Jon has already answered that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators)

Comment: I believe the | operand doesn't use short-circuit evaluation, so there is potentially a slight performance impact, probably negligible for this example.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/27/what-exactly-does-lifted-mean.aspx for a detailed discussion. Also, I will be returning to this subject later this month in my new blog, which is at http://ericlippert.com, if this subject interests you.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thanks for the link. What does the term `null` mean in the mathematical context?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Whatever you want it to mean :-) -- I'm assuming that there is some value called null that can go in a set. What precisely that value is depends on how you choose to construct the rest of the objects that can go in the set. There are a lot of sets to choose from, so surely we can find one that isn't being used for something else.

Comment: It is worth noting that the lifted `|` and `&` operators are an exception to the usual convention (usual in C# that is) for lifted binary operators. The "normal" case is to return `null` (of the `Nullable<>` type in question) as soon as just _one_ of the two operands does not `HasValue`. The binary comparison operators `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` in their lifted forms are another kind of exception since their lifted return type is `bool` in C#, not `bool?`.

Comment: @EricLippert (1) The blog post you linked doesn't mention the exception I just explained, so someone reading only that blog post might think Skeet's answer above is wrong (it is not!). (2) I hope you guys don't forget to fix [this misleading compiler warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046115/) with lifted relational operators on non-simple types.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I was responding to Olivier's comment about not knowning what "lifted" meant; since the C# language uses this term in an inconsistent way I thought it worthwhile to point that out. Jon's answer is, of course, correct.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: And I fixed that bug in Roslyn before I left. I am no longer one of "those guys". :-)

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
return ((ckbx1.IsChecked ?? false) ||
        (ckbx2.IsChecked ?? false) ||
        ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that if null, then it'll be false, you can use the ?? operator.

```
 private bool AtLeastOnePlatypusChecked()
 {
      return ((ckbx1.IsChecked ?? false) ||
      (ckbx2.IsChecked ?? false) ||
      (ckbx3.IsChecked ?? false) ||
      (ckbx4.IsChecked ?? false));
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `GetValueOrDefault()` to get either the value, or `false`.

```
private bool AtLeastOnePlatypusChecked()
{
    return ((ckbx1.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()) ||
            (ckbx2.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()) ||
            (ckbx3.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()) ||
            (ckbx4.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
(ckbx1.IsChecked.HasValue && ckbx1.IsChecked.Value)
```

Comment: Should the `||` be the `&&` operator? If `cbx1.IsChecked.HasValue` is `false` then there will be a `Null Reference` when getting `ckbx1.IsChecked.Value`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `??` operator inside your method;

```
private bool AtLeastOnePlatypusChecked()
{
return ((ckbx1.IsChecked ?? false) ||
        (ckbx2.IsChecked ?? false) ||
        (ckbx3.IsChecked ?? false) ||
        (ckbx4.IsChecked ?? false)
}
```