# ? Constructor handling with nullable types

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

small question, just for understanding: I have 2 nullable datetimes. I read out the create time and the update time, both can be filled. So I want to check which is later:

```
lastChangedIndrole = (tmpCreate > tmpUpdate ? tmpCreate : tmpUpdate);
```

But here happen some strange things. I would expect to throw a error when f.e. tmpUpdate is null, but it seem to return something, but not the corret value but just the second, in my example the update.

Is there anything I dont understand? I'd think the code checks the miliseconds to 1900 and if there is a null value an error gets thrown. But this doesnt happen. Is that some magic I dont understand?

P.S. : Is there a special word for the ? constructor like IIF in vb? It's hard to search something.

Thanks and a good start in the week

Matthias

Comment: *Why* would you expect that to throw an exception? Note that there's no constructor in the code you're talking about. Did you just mean "conditional operator" instead of "constructor"?

Comment: You may also be interested in checking if values are `null` or equals to `DateTime.MinValue`, it is important to make sure data is valid before assigning the result of operations to another variable (resulting to another strange behaviors and difficult to debug).

Comment: I think you meant to use the word "construct", not "constructor", as the latter word has a special meaning in .NET and C# (and indeed lots of programming languages), whereas "construct" means something assembled from smaller parts, or a statement/sentence constructed by assembling terms and ideas.

Comment: I didnt write the whole code. My question is just like: When the code checks the value of a nullable value and it is null AND it checks if this value is bigger than another value, how is he handling it? Since checking on a null ref type throws errors, I'd expect the same with nullable types?

Comment: take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399932/why-does-return-false-when-returns-true-for-null-values

Comment: Here is the Microsoft article explaining comparison with nullable types, and the reults of it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx#sectionToggle4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare two `DateTime?` objects, but most of the time, when at least one of the operands is `null`, the result will be `false`.

For example:

```
DateTime? today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime? yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
DateTime? nodate = null;
DateTime? nodate2 = null;

Console.WriteLine(today > yesterday); //true
Console.WriteLine(today < yesterday); //false

Console.WriteLine(today > nodate); //false
Console.WriteLine(today == nodate); //false
Console.WriteLine(today < nodate); //false

Console.WriteLine(nodate > yesterday); //false
Console.WriteLine(nodate == yesterday); //false
Console.WriteLine(nodate < yesterday); //false

Console.WriteLine(nodate > nodate2); //false
Console.WriteLine(nodate == nodate2); //true - this is the exception
Console.WriteLine(nodate < nodate2); //false
```

I would recommend avoiding being too clever, and being more explicit in the code:

```
if (tmpUpdate.HasValue)
{
   if (tmpCreate.HasValue)
   {
       lastChangedIndrole = (tmpCreate > tmpUpdate ? tmpCreate : tmpUpdate);
   }
   else
   {
       lastChangedIndrole = tmpUpdate;
   }
}
else
{
   if (tmpCreate.HasValue)
   {
       lastChangedIndrole = tmpCreate;
   }
   else
   {
       lastChangedIndrole = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I just make sure the values are not null when I check them, so I cant run into this problems.

Answer (score 3):

Nullable types being null throws exception when `Nullable.Value` read. But it won't throw exception when compparing it will give unexpected results though(Comparing `null` with non-null value never returns true).

Following snippet will illustrate the problem

```
DateTime? dt1 = null;
DateTime? dt2 = DateTime.Now;

bool b1 = dt2 > dt1;//false(we expect true here)
bool b2 = dt2 < dt1;//false
bool b3 = dt2 == dt1;//false
```

This behavior is documented [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

> When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to false except for != (not equal). It is important not to assume that because a particular comparison returns false, the opposite case returns true. In the following example, 10 is not greater than, less than, nor equal to null. Only num1 != num2 evaluates to true.

Answer (score 3):

C# lifts the `<` and `>` operators over nullable types, and they return `false` if one of the arguments is null.

Therefore `tmpCreate > tmpUpdate` evaluates to `false` if `tmpCreate` or `tmpUpdate` are null.

It is described in the specification:

**7.3.7 Lifted operators**

> • For the relational operators <  >  <=  >= a lifted form of an
>   operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types
>   and if the result type is bool. The lifted form is constructed by
>   adding a single ? modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator
>   produces the value false if one or both operands are null. Otherwise,
>   the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying
>   operator to produce the bool result.

Comment: `((int?)null) == ((int?)null)` == `true`. I hate nullable comparisons :-) Building truth tables for them is heavy headache level.

Comment: @xanatos - Yes, you're right about `==`. I've removed it since it's not relevant to this question.

Comment: Interesting... the `<=` and `>=` are lifted completely... So `null == null`, but !`null <= null`

Answer (score 1):

When you compare nullable values, either to other nullable values, or to non-nullable values, operators on the non-nullable types are "lifted", and thus also apply to their nullable counterparts.

However, special handling will handle the case where either or both are null.

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) example:

```
void Main()
{
    int? a = 10;
    int? b = null;

    (a > b).Dump();
    (b > a).Dump();
    (a == b).Dump();
    (a != b).Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
False
False
False
True
```

As you can see, when comparing two nullable ints, where one is `null`, only the equality operators produces the expected result.

If we make the `a` variable a non-nullable int:

```
int a = 10;
```

but otherwise keep the code, then it produces the exact same results.

What if both are null?

```
int? a = null;
int? b = null;
```

Produces:

```
False
False
True
False
```

Conclusion:

- Equality operators (`==` and `!=`) correctly handle `null`s with nullable types
- Less than or greater than operators does not, they will return `false` if one of the operands is `null`, even if you switch the comparison around. Basically, `10` is neither less than or greater than `null`.

If you try to read the `.Value` property of a `null` nullable type value, it will throw an exception, but the operators do not go directly for the `.Value` property, but check the `.HasValue` property first, and then handle these cases before attempting the actual comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` (xor) to check if exactly one condition is true (equals null) then `??` to return the first not-null value. If both are not null use your existing expression.

```
if (tmpCreate == null ^ tmpUpdate == null)
   lastChangedIndrole = tmpCreate ?? tmpUpdate;
else
   lastChangedIndrole = (tmpCreate > tmpUpdate ? tmpCreate : tmpUpdate);
```

But you could also choose to assign the first non-null value directly and then overwrite it if tmpUpdate is larger than the value:

```
lastChangedInRole = tmpCreate ?? tmpUpdate; 
if (tmpUpdate > lastChangedInRole) 
  lastChangedInRole = tmpUpdate;
```

(Rationale: If only one has a value, the comparison will always be false and the non null value will be assigned using `??`, otherwise the `tmpCreated` will be assigned and it is only neccessary to compare it to `tmpUpdate`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use ^ (xor) to check if exactly one condition is true ( equals null) then ?? to return the first not-null value. If both are not null use your existing expression.

if (tmpCreate == null ^ tmpUpdate == null)
lastChangedIndrole = tmpCreate ?? tmpUpdate;
else
lastChangedIndrole = (tmpCreate > tmpUpdate ? tmpCreate : tmpUpdate);